# Create new column if value appears in column of other data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe `dfA` with a column `SubscriberID`.

I would like to create a new column (`ReceivedPre`), populated with `1` or `0`, depending on if the `SubscriberID` value appears in the column of another dataframe, `dfB`

I tried the following:

```
within(dfA, {
  ReceivedPre = ifelse(SubID == dfB$SubID, 1, 0)
})
```

But get a warning message:

```
Warning message:
In SubID == dfB$SubID :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I don't think it is executing entirely correct, as I should get significantly more `1` values in my `ReceivedPre` column.

Comment: You can also solve this task in `dplyr`. Interested in seeing the solution?

Comment: Yes, that would be great! Interested :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we use `within`, the assignment would be `<-` instead of `=` and also use `%in%` instead of `==`

```
within(dfA, {
   ReceivedPre  <- ifelse(SubID %in% dfB$SubID, 1, 0)
   })
```

Otherwise, it can `transform`

```
transform(dfA, ReceivedPre = as.integer(SubID %in% dfB$SubID))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dfA <- dfA %>% mutate(ReceievedPre = if_else(SubID %in% dfB$SubID, 1, 0))
```